# Как создавать контролы на чистом X11?

Tags: c++, x11

Решил изучить работу с протоколом X11.

Застрял на том что не могу понять как создать например LineEdit или выпадающий список.

Правильно понимаю что X11 предоставляет только окна в виде прямоугольника, а все что касается элементов управления остальное лепится из них?

Просто если взять например GDI Windows то он предоставляет готовые элементы управления такие как редактирование текста или выпадающий список например.

Comment: Правильно понимаете. Вообще X11 предоставляет методы для рисования простых фигур, но на практике ими никто не пользуется (а в Wayland их вообще нет)

Comment: примерный аналог X11 в windows это WMF